# Word that means "to complete another person's sentence"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Example:

> "She doesn't eat meat. I think she's a ..." he trailed off.
>
> "Vegetarian?" I [...].

The only word I could think of is *interjected*. But I think it's wrong, because it implies [*interruption*](https://www.google.com.tw/search?q=interjected&spell=1&sa=X&ved=0CBoQvwUoAGoVChMIqqnsvq-rxwIVhBiUCh2knwIT&biw=1280&bih=938), while the example implies *addition.*

What's a more appropriate word?

Comment: I doubt there's a normal word specifically meaning *to complete another person's [unfinished] sentence.* Given the *question mark*, I'd say ***suggested*** could work, but I bet in practice a lot of writers would simply go with *I **finished the thought*** or similar.

Comment: This is usually called *finishing* another's sentence.  I don't know of a single word.

Comment: Many if not most written instances of [*supplied hesitantly*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22supplied+hesitantly%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) match OP's context. But I'm voting to close as Primarily Opinion-based.

Comment: **What a fantastic question.**  Jano, do you mean when someone INTERRUPTS and FINISHES YOUR SENTENCES FOR YOU ("like your Grandma always does!").  Or do you mean when I say something, an GET STUCK (can't think of the word), and you come in and finish the sentence for me?? The two are different.

Comment: Almost all your questions are fantastic, Jano.

Comment: Joe Blow has identified two interpretations, and they're significantly different between them. Could you please clarify which type of "word filler" verb you are asking about. A) the person who interrupts you before you have finished b) or fills in the missing blank,  the word that is on the tip of your tongue.

Comment: ... chipped in.

Comment: Mari - that being said, I did now actually read the question. Notice the "trailed off" ... so perhaps it's more "B" in my posed duality....I typed, dribbling off halfheartedly.

Comment: I get so much out of eventually reading the questions.

Comment: @JoeBlow -  This is a discussion that has now become chat. Let's focus on the question.

Comment: jano Chen - Please can you look at the answers so far, see if they are useful, decide whether you need to refine your question. Otherwise we have people continuing to guess. Thanks.

Comment: @Joe Blow Well, just trailing off. Like I mentioned in my question.

Comment: https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2013/07/sentence-interruptus.html might be of interest. Personally I don't find it annoying at all and when it happens with me (either end) it is someone I’m very close to (whether or not with). They talk about the ability to 'just know' (and that it's not real) and there really is something to that (to the contrary of their statement) but I won't get into that either. This article suggests there is no single word for it. Another possibility could be 'complement' but that doesn't really work in my mind at least. Great question though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"She doesn't eat meat. I think she's a ..." he trailed off.

"Vegetarian?" I **volunteered**.

> **volunteer**
>
> 1.2 [reporting verb] Say or suggest something without being asked:  [with object]: ‘it never paid to volunteer information’
>
> [with direct speech]: ‘‘Her name’s Louise,’ Christina volunteered’
>
> [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/volunteer)

Comment: In the very specific example given, Jano, I would use "I continued".

Comment: @JoeBlow - That doesn't work in my opinion. If you *continue* then you carry on where *you* left off. You do not continue something that someone else has spoken.  Example: *He left his peas on the plate so I continued eating them*", It just doesn't' work.

Comment: It's a tough one.  If you "continue" something it means you continue it: indeed I can be continuing my work, your work, society's work .. or whatever. "Who will continue this?" "I will!" {or more likely ... "uh, hopefully someone else will."}  Hence, I'm saying: " If you continue then you carry on where you left off." ... I disagree, continue means continue. But I fully appreciate that in that context, you'd perhaps more likely say **"I continued for her."**  Indeed, that would be the common solution here. But IMO Churchill would just write "I continued"...continued means continued.

Comment: I like "volunteered". Another good one that could work in this specific example is "ventured" which isn't exactly what the asker requested.

Comment: Maybe you should make that an answer. 'ventured' goes well with the question mark.

Answer (score 5):

Note: I do not find this answer better than the previous, I just want to make an extended comment with some formatting.

[***posit***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/posit?s=ts):

> 1. to place, put, or set.
> 2. to lay down or assume as a fact or principle; postulate.

*"Vegetarian?" I **posited.***

I like this verb because you use both meanings.  The connotation can be "fill in the blank," at least to me.

But most examples online are seemingly drawn from people talking about the scientific method—only postulating, not placing—so someone tell me how idiomatic this is.

Answer (score 0):

IMO a common solution here is

> "She doesn't eat meat. I think she's a ..." he trailed off.
>      "Vegetarian?" I continued for her.

or

> "She doesn't eat meat. I think she's a ..." he trailed off.
>   "Vegetarian?" I finished the sentence.

Note that for me, "he trailed off" doesn't really work like that.

or

> "She doesn't eat meat. I think she's a ..." he said, trailing off.
>      "... vegetarian?" I picked up.

Just to be clear, "volunteered" (see other answer) is perfect here, if that's the feel you want.  (If you want **"brusquely added"** ... say that.  If you want **"quickly completed"** ... say that.  if you want **"hesitatingly suggested"** ... say that.)

{Don't forget ... writing is about actions. The words are nothing, zero. It's like drawing is about looking. The pencil marks are nothing, zero.}